# 'Pre-retargeting' - How does it work (if it does)

Tags: advertising

I have been approached by a couple of advertising agencies whom offer a service they're touting as being call 'pre-retargeting'.

Apparently it's possible to serve display ads to users that visit *competitor* websites, as opposed to re targeting where you're serving ads to users that have visited your own site.

I'm skeptical as I don't understand where this data would even be available? If it is possible, and does work, it's a very interesting approach for us.

Does anyone have experience, or an understanding whether this service is legit?

Comment: If downvoting, please leave a comment so that I can improve the question. It seems the same subject has been discussed on Quora but without a solid answer https://www.quora.com/Retargeting/Is-it-possible-to-target-remarketing-ads-to-visitors-of-competitor-sites-or-interest-group-sites

Comment: I would put a scam flag on that. For example a tool that show your ads specifically is AdWords and it is based on what kind of sites are you interested in taking a peek at your most used keywords and visited sites, facebook ads work the same way but it  has nothing to do with competitors. In fact an advertise feature wouldn't offer their service by telling you we will display your ad on your competitor's website because that's just scumbag..

Comment: Thanks knif3r I thought the same although one of the agencies in question seems fairly established. I think I'll leave this one for now until I hear some more info.

Comment: If you are interested in advertising I would suggest to use AdWords, also it provides access to google keyword tool so you can reconsider your featured keywords having a database with the most entered keywords in the search query is a big of advantage.

Comment: We already use Adwords (I head online marketing for a fairly large aviation group).  We're in a high-value niche so competitor's visitors would have been v interesting. Thanks for your advice though.